# Share clipboard between ubuntu and windows 10

Tags: windows, ubuntu, xfce

I routinely remote log into (RDP) my ubuntu box (running xfce desktop environment) from my Windows 10 PC. I have not been able to copy and paste content from one system to another. Is there a way to share clipboard between the two systems?

Comment: If Windows 10 uses the same dialog as Windows 7, have you tried this? http://www.technipages.com/unable-to-copy-and-paste-to-remote-desktop-session

Comment: Yes, Win 10 has same dialog. But even after enabling drive as the article suggests, copy and paste still does not work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Okay, so Windows isn't the problem. What RDP program are you using on Ubuntu?

Comment: xrdp, I suppose. I am using xfce4 desktop manager as well.